# In welchen Regionen/Dialekten sagt man Ihr zueinander?

Tags: dialect, formality

Mir ist bekannt, dass die Höflichkeitsform im Berndeutschen *Ihr* ist, und dass dies früher weiter verbreitet resp. Standard (soweit man von der Existenz eines Standards reden kann) war. Da wirft sich natürlich die Frage auf, ob es noch andere Dialekte gibt, in denen *Ihr* nicht durch *Sie* ersetzt wurde.

Natürlich meine ich hier eine Verwendung unabhängig vom Numerus, also nicht nur als Plural-Ansprache, sondern auch explizit im Singular, genau so eben wie *Sie* auch verwendet wird.

Comment: Sich zu _Ihrzen_ ist eine sehr kreative Extrapolation von _Siezen_ :-D. Glückwunsch dazu!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ falls du dich auf das Wort beziehst, sure I guess, nicht meine Erfindung. Falls du den Vorgang selber meinst, ist das soweit ich weiss eher anders herum. Nach [wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronominale_Anredeform#Moderne_Zeit_(1800_bis_um_2000)) ist das _Siezen_ relativ neu (ende 17. Jh), _Ihrzen_ nach der gleichen Seite schon ein Jahrtausend früher.

Comment: Ich kenne das Ihrzen aus Gegenden in Süddeutschland, wo der Dialekt noch eher verbreitet ist. Manchmal ist es aber meinem Gefühl nach  auch nur der "dritte Weg", wenn man nicht weiß, ob man die Leute jetzt siezen oder duzen soll.

Comment: @tofro Wenn man ein Pärchen anspricht, macht es den Gebrauch leichter :-D

Comment: @Adarain Der von Dir im Kommentar verlinkte Wikipedia-Artikel beinhaltete zwei Absätze zur regionalen Verbreitung des Ihrzens (Abschnitt "Anrede mit Ihr - Gegenüber Einzelpersonen"). Ist Deine Frage damit nicht beantwortet? Wenn nicht, warum nicht?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Der Artikel ist meiner Meinung nach recht vage und es lässt sich nicht wirklich schliessen, dass da nichts ausgelassen wird

Comment: @Marzipanherz Er fragt nach den spezifischen Dialekten, in denen diese Art der Ansprache üblich ist. Das Ergebnis wäre folglich eine Aufzählung dieser mit entsprechenden Referenzen.

Comment: @Adarain Ich würde Dir empfehlen, die Frage weitergehend dahin zu spezifizieren, ob mit _Ihr_ tatsächlich die angesprochene Person gemeint ist, oder nicht etwa die Person instant einer Institution, Firma, Gruppe o.ä,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ja. 3. Plural als Anrede für Einzelne ist noch im Gebrauch.

Comment: @Stephie Ich hatte ja auch nicht gezweifelt, dass dies so ist. Aber die Frage bedarf eventuell der Klärung genau dieses Punktes. Ansonsten ist es nämlich ziemlich gebräuchlich (unabhängig von Dialekt oder Region).

Comment: @Stephie: man könnte ja sagen, dass *Sie* auch ein Plural ist und das ist noch sehr gebräuchlich. <g>

Comment: There is an interesting discussion here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/er-anrede-18-jhd.2526030/#post-12724138

Answer (score 4):

Keine Antwort im Sinne der Vollständigkeit, aber in manchen Donauschwäbischen Gruppen bzw. Rückkehrern ist „Ihr“ als Höflichkeitsanrede für Einzelpersonen noch im Gebrauch, wenngleich schwindend - weil die Adressaten schlicht aussterben.

Ich bin selbst (geb. in den 70ern) noch damit aufgewachsen, dass ältere Tanten und Onkel (geboren bis ca. in den 30ern im damaligen Jugoslawien, nach Deutschland gekommen in den späten 50ern) eben mit „Ihr“ angesprochen werden.

Answer (score 2):

Ich als ältere Person benutze 'ihr' häufig als Kunde, wenn ich mit einem Verkäufer oder Service-Mitarbeiter spreche, in der Bedeutung 'Ihr Unternehmen'. Beispiel:

> Habt ihr inzwischen wieder Küchenrollen da oder sind die noch nicht wieder geliefert worden?

Mit diesem 'ihr' meine ich 'ihr alle, die ihr dort arbeitet'. Wie das von der jüngeren Person verstanden wird, weiß ich nicht. Es kam auch schon mal vor, dass sich jemand dadurch 'pluralisch geduzt' fühlte, ist aber schon 'ne Weile her, da war der Altersabstand zur angesprochenen Person noch nicht so groß.

Ich selbst empfinde eine ungefragte Anrede mit 'ihr' tendenziell nicht ebenso respektlos wie ein direktes Duzen.

Es mag sein, dass ich früher selbst in diesem Sinne angesprochen wurde und das als eine Art Dialekt-Respektform 'Ihr' verstanden hatte.